# ServiceStack: How to unit test a service that serves files

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, servicestack, servicestack-text

I have a web service that service an Excel file

```
public class ReportService : Service
{
    public IReportRepository Repository {get; set;}

    public object Get(GetInvoiceReport request)
    {
        var invoices = Repository.GetInvoices();

        ExcelReport report = new ExcelReport();
        byte[] bytes = report.Generate(invoices);

        return new FileResult(bytes);
    }
}
```

and I setup the object that is retured from the service as

```
public class FileResult : IHasOptions, IStreamWriter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _responseStream;
    public IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; private set; }

    public BinaryFileResult(byte[] data)
    {
        _responseStream = new MemoryStream(data);

        Options = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"InvoiceFile.xlsx\";"}
        };
    }

    public void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
    {
        if (_responseStream == null)
            return;

        using (_responseStream)
        {
            _responseStream.WriteTo(responseStream);
            responseStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _responseStream.Close();
        _responseStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, the webservice works fine when tested through a browser; but it gives an error message when tested from a unit test. Below is the error message:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Type definitions
>   should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'FileResult', got
>   string starting with:
>   PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0000\u0008\u0000�\u000b5K���%\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0000\u0000[Content_Types].xml��
>   at
>   ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(TypeConfig
>   typeConfig, StringSegment strType, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn,
>   Dictionary`2 typeAccessorMap)    at
>   ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__1(StringSegment value)    at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1.Parse(StringSegment
>   value)    at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1.Parse(String value)
>   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String
>   value)    at
>   ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream[T](Stream
>   stream)    at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.GetResponse[TResponse](WebResponse
>   webResponse)    at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod,
>   String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)

Below is the unit test I used to test the webservice:

```
[Test]
public void TestInvoiceReport()
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/report/");

    var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate
                {
                    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
                    UserName = "[User Name]",
                    Password = "[Password]"
                }); 

    var requestDTO = new GetInvoiceReport();

    var ret = client.Get<FileResult>(requestDTO);

    Assert.IsTrue(ret != null);
}
```

**Edit:**
I am including the definition for my request DTO class:

```
[Route("/invoices", "GET")]
public class GetInvoiceReport: IReturn<FileResult>
{

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: if you're making a HTTP Request instead of calling the Service in code, it's an [Integration Test](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing) instead of a Unit Test.

You haven't provided your `GetInvoiceReport` Request DTO definition, but if you're returning anything that's not a serialized DTO it should be specified it its `IReturn<T>` interface, e.g:

```
public class GetInvoiceReport : IReturn<byte[]> { ... }
```

Then you'll be able to download the raw bytes with:

```
byte[] response = client.Get(new GetInvoiceReport());
```

You can use the Service Clients Request Filters for inspecting the HTTP Response Headers.

I'd also recommend checking out ServiceStack's .NET Service Clients docs which contains extensive info for [downloading raw Responses](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#support-for-native-built-in-response-types).

Comment: mythz: I have updated the question to include the class for my request DTO. BTW, I tried your suggestion by adding " : IReturn<byte[]>" to my request DTO and used "byte[] response = client.Get(new GetInvoiceReport());" in my unit test but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: @ErmiasY Please update your question to show the exact code you're using + the new Exception with the new code.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing from different browser tabs. The question should be be fully updated now.

Comment: @ErmiasY Please read by answer carefully, your interface should be `IReturn<byte[]>`, you're returning raw bytes, not `FileResult` which is not a serialized DTO. Please also read the docs on [downloading raw responses with the .NET Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#support-for-native-built-in-response-types)

Comment: Thanks. I will check the link you provided.